# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.config' has no attribute 'set_visible_devices'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, gpu

First of all, I apologize that my English is not good for you to understand.
Currently, I am doing computer vision using tensorflow version 1.14. In the process, the following problem ocurred in the process of rotating the model using GPU.

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.config' has no attribute 'set_visible_devices'**

The current development environment is as follows.

- Python: 3.7.9
- conda: 4.8.3
- tensorflow: 1.14.0
- keras: 2.3.1

In addition, I currently have 4 gpu, and i want to use 2 gpu as if it were 1 gpu. Can you give me a good idea for this?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to upgrade the tensorflow because `tf.config.set_visible_devices()` function is available in latest version of tensorflow, you can use below code to upgrade the tensorflow:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip.
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

You can follow the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) to install the CPU/GPU version of tensorflow as per requirement and for `tf.config.set_visible_devices()` function related details, check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_visible_devices)